# Xdebug:Time-out connecting to debugging client

Tags: laravel, docker-compose, laravel-sail

I am trying to setup xdebug using laravel sail with latest version, on my Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS desktop,

ie
php 8.1
laravel 9

with below mentioned details to .env file

```
SAIL_XDEBUG_MODE=develop,debug
SAIL_XDEBUG_CONFIG="client_host=172.23.0.1"
```

but when i run `sail debug migrate`, returns

`Xdebug: [Step Debug] Time-out connecting to debugging client, waited: 200 ms. Tried: 172.23.0.1:9003 (through xdebug.client_host/xdebug.client_port)`

When I tried finding IP, it change every time 
`docker inspect -f {{range.NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.Gateway}}{{end}} <container-name>`
return different IP  like 172.25.0.1

Answer (score 3):

I've been searching on this till I read about it being a firewall port issue [here](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/laravel-9-with-sail-xdebug-not-connecting).

Then I remember the `services.[laravel.test].ports` on *docker-compose.yml* and tried to add `9003:9003` ports.

##### Try adding the XDebug ports:

```
services:
    laravel.test:
        build:
            context: ...
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
            args:
                WWWGROUP: '${WWWGROUP}'
        image: ...
        extra_hosts:
            - 'host.docker.internal:host-gateway'
        ports:
            - '${APP_PORT:-80}:80'
            - '${VITE_PORT:-5173}:${VITE_PORT:-5173}'
            - '9003:9003'
        ...
```

Answer (score 0):

### Solution

Just put this in your `.env` the following

```
SAIL_XDEBUG_MODE=develop,debug
SAIL_XDEBUG_CONFIG="client_host=host.docker.internal"
```

Just as in Windows and MacOS

Now you can run `sail debug migrate` or just `sail debug` in order to test it.

#### Explanation

You're probably using `sail down` to 'stop' the containers, but as the [docker documentation stated](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/down/):

> docker-compose down
>
> ...
>
> Stops containers and removes containers, networks, volumes, and images created by `up`.
>
> By default, the only things removed are:
>
> - Containers for services defined in the Compose file
> - ***Networks defined in the networks section of the Compose file***
> - The default network, if one is used

Thus, every time you're running `sail up` it will regenerate the network with a new IP address.

You could use `sail stop`, but when you're working with multiple projects it could become a hassle to edit the ports (in the `.env` file) of every service per project.

As per [v1.10.1](https://github.com/laravel/sail/releases/tag/v1.10.1), sail incorporate the [`extra_host` option](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#extra_hosts), essentially detecting the [IP of the host machine](https://github.com/laravel/sail/pull/222#issue-974186753):

> With this, every time we create/start the application container the host.docker.internal mapping will be created and will point to the host machine.

*Edit: Do not forget to update Docker since this only works with Docker v20.10+.*

Comment: not work ;Listening to Xdebug on localhost:9003 failed: Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use 127.0.0.1:9003